# pip permission issue on OS X

Tags: python, macos, pip

I can't automatically update **pip** because it alway show error with permission:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'
```

Command for update:

> sudo -H pip freeze --local | grep -v '^-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sudo` command doesn't apply to the whole pipe; it only applies to the first `pip freeze` command.

You'll need to use `sudo` on the `xargs` command too:

```
sudo -H pip freeze --local | grep -v '^-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs sudo -H pip install -U
```

Alternatively, use `sudo` to create a new sub-shell and run your pipe in that:

```
sudo -H bash -c 'pip freeze --local | grep -v \'^-e\' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs pip install -U'
```